# How to use crosstab to get values in proper columns?

Tags: postgresql, crosstab

I have a crosstab SQL where I did not get expected result as output. I got all the values on the first column. Here is my sql:

```
select * from crosstab 
('select p.name::text as product,
 pc.name as prod_cat,
 sum( ms.qtyonhand) as total_stock from adempiere.m_product p 
 join adempiere.m_product_category pc on p.m_product_category_id=pc.m_product_category_id 
 join adempiere.m_storage ms on ms.m_product_id=p.m_product_id 
 group by prod_cat,product order by 3 desc') as ct 

(product text,
 "ELECTRICAL & ELECTRONIC ITEMS" numeric,
 "ACADEMICS BOOKS" numeric,
 "Standard" numeric,
 "FOOD AND BEVERAGES" numeric,
 "Possibly Product Category" numeric, 
 "Pharmacy Medicine" numeric,
  "COMPUTER & ACCESSORIES" numeric) 
limit 10
```

and this is the output I got: https://i.stack.imgur.com/w6gc5.png

This is the output I am looking for:

```
product              | Electricals |   Electronics |  Food & Beverages |  Cosmetics |  Hardwares  
---------------------|-------------|---------------|-------------------|------------|-------------
Samsung-WM           |             |     4552      |                   |            |          
Videocon-Refridge    |             |     1254      |                   |            |             
Philips-CFL Bulbs    |   5677      |               |                   |            |             
Head&shoulder Shampoo|             |               |                   |     4567   |             
Candysweet           |             |               |       5678        |            |             
Icecreams            |             |               |       6785        |            |             
Paints               |             |               |                   |            |      9876   
Taps                 |             |               |                   |            |     10987   
Electrical wires     |  18796      |               |                   |            |
```

How can I modify my query to get the proper result?

Comment: dont' post images post the data. and what was the output you expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the function with two queries: [`crosstab(text source_sql, text category_sql)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html). 
In the second query select all possible category values in desired order.

---

Simple example - my home budget:

```
create table expenses (subject text, person text, cost int);
insert into expenses values
('dress', 'wife', 200),
('toy', 'son', 100),
('beer', 'me', 50);
```

Summary:

```
select * 
from crosstab (
    $ct$
    select * from expenses
    order by 1, 2
    $ct$
    ) as ct (subject text, wife int, son int, me int);

 subject | wife | son | me 
---------+------+-----+----
 beer    |   50 |     |   
 dress   |  200 |     |   
 toy     |  100 |     |   
(3 rows)
```

Well, this is not what I could trust.

When the query produces data with holes, you should tell `crosstab()` how it can recognize which `value` belong to which `category`:

```
select * 
from crosstab (
    $ct$
    select * from expenses
    order by 1, 2
    $ct$,
    $ct$ 
    select person from expenses
    order by 1 desc
    $ct$
    ) as ct (subject text, wife int, son int, me int);

 subject | wife | son | me 
---------+------+-----+----
 beer    |      |     | 50
 dress   |  200 |     |   
 toy     |      | 100 |   
(3 rows)
```

The second query simply returns a list of categories: `'wife', 'son', 'me'` (the order is important). 
You might use `values ('wife'), ('son'), ('me')` as well.

Comment: Would you please give me an example ?